# set value to array of getElementsByName

Tags: javascript, dynamic, getelementsbyname

I am having the following situation:

I must use dynamic table (add/remove rows) - code from http://viralpatel.net/blogs/dynamically-add-remove-rows-in-html-table-using-javascript/

rows contain html input boxes with name, no id

I need to be able to set values to these boxes

I have tried the following, but get into syntax problem:

<!-- html part -> this row will be replicated by the dynamic table code -->

```
<tr><td><input type=input name=mybox></td></tr>

//js part - variant 1:
document.getElementsByName("mybox").item(j).value = j;

//js part - variant 2:
document.getElementsByName("mybox")[j].setAttribute("value", j);
```

None of these seems to work. 
Can you suggest a right way to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: what will you get if you use `alert(document.getElementsByName("mybox").length);` with the script will it return the total number input tags you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.getElementsByName("mybox")[j].value = j;`

Answer (score 1):

`getElementsByName` returns an array of HTMLElements.

This line has the correct syntax but I doubt `j`, the value you are trying to set is the right index value of the returned array.

```
document.getElementsByName("mybox")[j].setAttribute("value", j);
```

The fist occurrence of `j` should be the index of the returned array. If It's the first element found by the given name then 0, if the 2nd, then 1, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your html code seems wrong, try put the double quotes:

```
<tr><td><input type="input" name="mybox"></td></tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

We don't know what is the value of `j` and how it's being set.

First variant should work. Just set a value that makes sense.
For testing purposes: `document.getElementsByName("mybox")[3].value = "Test";`

Also use quotes for attributes `type="input"` and `name="mybox"`

Answer (score 0):

try this  `$("#mybox").eq(j).val("your value");`

Answer (score 0):

thank you for the feedback.

Michal's solution is the one I got working.

```
document.getElementsByName("mybox")[3].value = "Test";
```

= = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =

However I tried my 2nd variant as suggested by Marcell Fülöp in a very rudimentary way and saw some strange behaviour:

```
//manual assignment of indexes
document.getElementsByName("mybox")[0].setAttribute("value",0);
document.getElementsByName("mybox")[1].setAttribute("value",1);
document.getElementsByName("mybox")[2].setAttribute("value",2);
```

The strange result was only the 1st box got it's value. I'd be happy to understand why...